# Cookies get cleared during page reload in asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, cookies, session-cookies

I am setting the cookies in asp.net like this

```
      obj.opts.on('click', function () {
                var opt = $(this);
                obj.val = opt.text();
                obj.index = opt.index();
                obj.namePlaceholder.text(obj.val);
                obj.idPlaceholder.val(opt.attr('id'));
                document.cookie = "CityID=" + opt.attr('id');
                setCookie("CityID", DateTime.Now, 365);
                window.location.href = window.location.href;
```

and when I debug the value of cookies in serverside and every time  it gets cleared.
   I am ckecking cookies like this

```
        if (Response.Cookies["CityID"].Value == null)
        {
           .....
        }
```

everi time this condition satisfies. any help to retain the cookies will surele be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing more of the code, my first guess would be you want to look at Request.Cookies and not Response.Cookies.

Comment: +1 - clearly one need to look at `Request.Cookies` to see cookies set by browser's code. Side note: Most likely using of `Response.Cookies` is caused by ASP.Net server side magic that copies cookies set on `Response` to `Request` and thus triggering assumption the cookies can be checked on just either request or response all the time.